# Problems installing Android SDK updates

Tags: android, sdk

I have downloaded the Android SDK manager and after selecting the Updates, tools, platform I want installed it comes up with the  message: 'Downloading sdk platform android 3.2' then an error message reads 'File not found c:\program files\android\android-adk\temp\sdk platform android 3.2.zip (Access is denied)' 
Don't understand how it could be anything to do with file permissions as there has been no zip files installed  in the temp folder!!!
Any help would be appreciated.

1. I am running winZip Evaluation version
2. All other programs are closed
3. File permission: read only for files in temp folder.

Thanks in advance

Comment: right click on eclipse icon and try to Run as admin...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run it as an Administrator. Open your `Eclipse` or `SDK manager` by right clicking and `run as administrator`. that should work.

Comment: Many thanks, a simple answer that works, seems to be downloading o.k now. have a tick on me

Comment: it takes forever long. i had to keep it overnight. cant help that.